# What is the pullback of the adjoint representation on a Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, pullback

On a Lie Algebra, we often work with the adjoint representation

\begin{align*}
\text{ad}_u: \mathfrak{g}&\to\mathfrak{g}\\
v&\mapsto [u,v].
\end{align*}

Provided we have some symmetric, positive definite map $A : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}^*$ to define an inner product , what would be the explicit form of the pullback $\text{ad}_u^*$ defined by

$$\text{ad}_u^*(A(v))(w) = A(v)(\text{ad}_u w)?$$

I initially thought that this pullback should be equal to
$$\text{ad}_u^* =  A \circ \text{ad}_u \circ A^{-1}$$
but after some work it seems that this is only true if the induced metric is left and right invariant.